# returning largest value (ASCII)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this code

```
function maxNum (array, str = -Infinity){
    var max = 0;
    var a = array.length;
    var b = "";
    for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] > max)
        {
            max = array[counter];
        }
        else if (max < b){
            max = b;
        }
    }
    return max > str ? max : str
}
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 5], 10));// output will be 10
```

It recieves an array and a value and return the largest num.(only numbers)

how can I make it work if a character is given, use the ASCII value of that char and return the result
how can I implement the `String.charCodeAt():` to the code?

I want the output of `([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 10)` to be `'a'`

and

I want the output of `([1,2,3,4,'a','b'],'a')` to be `'b'`

Comment: `a` and `b` are strings or number variable?

Comment: they are strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using array [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

```js
function maxNum(array, str = -Infinity) {
  return array.reduce((max, item) => {
    let itemc = isNaN(item) ? item.charCodeAt() : item;
    let maxc = isNaN(max) ? max.charCodeAt() : max;
    return max = (itemc > maxc) ? item : max;
  }, str)
}

console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 5], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a','c'], 'b'))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 'b'))
```

Your approach using `charCodeAt()`

```js
function maxNum(array, str = -Infinity) {
  var max = str;
  var a = array.length;
  for (counter = 0; counter < a; counter++) {
    let itemc = isNaN(array[counter]) ? array[counter].charCodeAt() : array[counter];
    let maxc = isNaN(max) ? max.charCodeAt() : max;
    if (itemc > maxc) {
      max = array[counter];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 5], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a','c'], 'b')) 
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 'b'))
```

Comment: thanks, how about output of `console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a','c'], 'b'))` should'nt the result be `'c'`??  cause it returns `'b'`  for (Your approach using charCodeAt())

Comment: @NewUser Sorry for that. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

To get the ASCII value of a single character, use [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

```js
const string = "J";
//ASCII "J" is 74
console.log(string.charCodeAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

using `concat` and `sort`

```js
function maxNum(array, str = -Infinity) {
  const charCode = (char) => isNaN(char) ? char.charCodeAt() : char;
  
  return [].concat(array, [str]).sort((a,b) => charCode(a) < charCode(b) ? 1 : -1)[0];
}

console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 5], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 10))
console.log(maxNum([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 'b'))
```

Comment: thanks that solution work,  but is there any other way to not use built-in functions like `concat` and `sort` in the code??

Comment: Keep in mind that sorting has `O(n log n)` time complexity

Comment: Thanks @Aswin Kumar. I do know that. Your solution is better than this. Itz just a flavor I came up with...

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxNum (array, str = -Infinity){
var max = 0;
var a = array.length;
var b = "";
for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
{
    let asc = array[counter];
    let asciicode = asc.toString().charCodeAt();
    if (asciicode > max)
    {
        max = asciicode ;
    }
    else if (max < b){
        max = b;
    }
}
return max > str ? max : str
}
console.log(String.fromCharCode( maxNum([1, 2, 3, 5, 'a', 'A', 's'], 10)));
```